# Is it possible to have temp tables in a function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, function, temp-tables

Apparently, I can't use them. I'm getting an error message like:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SELECT' within a function

If I want to do something like this:

```
select bleh
  into #temp
  from Blah
```

... inside a function.

Comment: You could use a table variable instead.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, per [this thread where the same question was asked](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic501942-145-1.aspx#bm1091906), you cannot, but you can use a `table variable`

```
DECLARE @MyTempTableVariable TABLE (SCHEMA)

INSERT INTO @MyTempTableVariable
SELECT bleh
FROM bleh
```

Comment: Cardinality error is the biggest reason why we would want to replace table variable with temp table in a SQL DB function. However there is a workaround for this issue as described in detail here:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blogdoezequiel/archive/2012/12/01/table-variables-and-row-estimations.aspx#.VGC5oMnm7HS 
Adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the statement where table variable is used may improve the performance.

Comment: This is not working for me... could this be because I've added a column in my table variable that is `INT IDENTITY(1,1)`?

Comment: Why have an identity for a table variable? These should be short lived and probably do not need IDENTITY - but that is my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with a CTE.  See the template browser in SSMS.  IntelliSense confuses the issue and will show an error until you complete the CTE and the following insert/select, but it will work.

Comment: This should have been a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @MohammadAkbari: I disagree. It adds a very valid alternative to the other answer.

Comment: @Lew Wolf: an example or some piece of code would be good, though.