# Invalid use side-effecting operator Insert within a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following code in my sql function:

```
if @max_chi > -999
begin
    INSERT INTO CH_TABLE(X1, X2, VALUE)
    VALUES(cur_out.sessionnumber, maxpos, max_chi)

    commit
end
```

The following is a SQL Server 2008 Query and it gives me an error:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within a function.

Why am I not allowed to do this? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Apparently holds for [temp tables too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844854/is-it-possible-to-have-temp-tables-in-a-function), though [you can use TABLE variables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9844898/1028230) to accomplish the same thing. Go figure.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can't use a function to insert data *into a base table*. Functions *return* data. This is listed as [the *very first* limitation in the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx):

> User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify the database state.

"Modify the database state" includes changing any data in the database (though a table variable is an obvious exception the OP wouldn't have cared about 3 years ago - this table variable only lives for the duration of the function call and does not affect the underlying tables in any way).

You should be using a stored procedure, not a function.

Comment: @mvv That might be a way to fake it but ask yourself why this needs to be done in a function in the first place, how comfortable you think the average user is opening up all the security implications of xp_cmdshell, and why you can't just use a procedure? Do you really want a scalar function that could be calling xp_cmdshell for every row in a 2 billion row table? I certainly don't. A function in T-SQL returns data, it is not meant to work the same as traditional functions in other languages.

Comment: @Fandango68, well I cannot despite my table being a variable

Comment: @AaronBertrand,  table variable change the state of database? Exception occurs even with a table variable and that is what I don't understand. It doesn't match the definition in the documentation.

Comment: @Cetin the engine blocks the `INSERT` - it doesn't matter what type of object the `INSERT` goes to (and yes, a table variable is stored on disk in tempdb, just like a temp table, so writing to it does "change state").

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that is very bad and I couldn't find a solution to this :( Thanks.

Comment: @Cetin What are you actually trying to do? "Insert within a function" is not a requirement. Why does your function need to insert anything?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Well I wouldn't but I am working on a database where there are some SPs already that I can't touch. One of them, I needed to run with different parameters and then compare the results. It looks like (insert into @ result1 exec mySP @  parm1; insert into @ result2 exec mySP @ parm2;) then my multistatement TVF would do some more work on them and place the result in its @ comparison table to return. As an SP it works, but not as a TVF :(

Comment: @Cetin Yeah, sounds like you need to create a new procedure because you shouldn't be using a MSTVF for that in the first place (note you can create [temporary stored procedures](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/) if you lack ability to create real ones).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks that is what I am doing at the end. I wish I could use MSTVF but anyway.

Answer (score 16):

Disclaimer: *This is not a solution, it is more of a hack to test out something. User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify the database state.*

I found one way to make insert or update using sqlcmd.exe so you need just to replace the code inside `@sql` variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[_tmp_func](@orderID NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql varchar(4000), @cmd varchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO _ord (ord_Code) VALUES (''' + @orderID + ''') '
SELECT @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @@servername +
              ' -d ' + db_name() + ' -Q "' + @sql + '"'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, 'no_output'
RETURN 1
END
```

Comment: "Found one way". You are basically calling sqlcmd.exe from inside sql (that even doesn't exist on Linux or Azure). This is a jerry-rig, a quick fix, a kludge, a McGyver kind of stupid thing. Please, don't! Circumvent a problem is not a solution!

Comment: JCKödel, I totally agree with you, it's not a solution, it's just one way to do it. Correct solution - you should be using a stored procedure, NOT A FUNCTION! Aaron Bertrand explained it very good(see the best answer to the current question above). And I would suggest avoiding usage of this solution, only to test out something...

Comment: @JCKödel That is all right. Now I'm using a function as intended. But, how do I suppose to find a bug within, if (AFAIK) there's no other way to log what's happening in the function?

Answer (score 8):

Functions cannot be used to modify base table information, use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

There is an exception (I'm using SQL 2014) when you are only using Insert/Update/Delete on Declared-Tables.  These Insert/Update/Delete statements cannot contain an OUTPUT statement.  The other restriction is that you are not allowed to do a MERGE, even into a Declared-Table.  I broke up my Merge statements, that didn't work, into Insert/Update/Delete statements that did work.

The reason I didn't convert it to a stored-procedure is that the table-function was faster (even without the MERGE) than the stored-procedure.  This is despite the stored-procedure allowing me to use Temp-Tables that have statistics.  I needed the table-function to be very fast, since it is called 20-K times/day.  This table function never updates the database.

I also noticed that the NewId() and RAND() SQL functions are not allowed in a function.

Comment: There is a simple workaround to use functions like RAND inside UDF function as you can see [here](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/121/Using-side-effecting-build-in-functions-inside-a-UDF-your-function.aspx). I am not saying that your should use but that it can be done