# Safely converting a function into a procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I've been converting an oracle schema to an sql server one and got the following error

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET COMMAND' within a function.

In my case modifying the database involved this

```
  set @originalDateFirst = @@DateFirst;
  set datefirst 1;
  set @DayOfWeek = datepart(weekday,@DATE); -- 1 to 5 = Weekday
  set datefirst originalDateFirst;
```

Ideally this wouldn't have modified the database but the `datepart` function uses static state.

I'm not really from a database background so was slightly baffled by this but reading [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389503/invalid-use-side-effecting-operator-insert-within-a-function) it looked like all I needed to do was swap the word function for procedure and I'd be away.  However I then got the following error

> Incorrect syntax near 'RETURNS'.

Reading around a bit about stored procedures aren't allowed to return anything they like - only integers. However the integers normally have the same semantics as a console application's return code - 0 is success and anything else is an error.

Luckily the type I wanted to return was an integer so fixing the next error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'RETURNS'.

Involved just removing

```
RETURNS INTEGER
```

from the function/procedure. However I'm unsure if there are any weird side effects caused by this error code interpretation that will be outside of my control. The function actually just returns either 0 or 1 basically as a true or false flag (where 1 is true and 0 is false as you might expect). Therefore one of my return values would count as an 'error'.

What if any are the consequences of piggybacking on the return code of a procedure rather than using an out parameter? Is it just a bad practice? If it's safe to do this I'd certainly prefer to so I don't need to change any calling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *isn't* an answer to your question as posed, but may be a better solution to the overall problem.

Rather than having to rely on a particular `DATEFIRST` setting, or *changing* the `DATEFIRST` setting, why not use an expression that always returns reliable results no matter *what* the `DATEFIRST` setting is.

For example, this expression:

```
select (DATEPART(weekday,GETDATE()) + 7 - DATEPART(weekday,'20140406')) % 7
```

always returns 1 on Mondays, 2 on Tuesdays, ..., 5 on Fridays. No matter what settings are in effect.

So, your entire original block of 4 lines of code could just be:

```
set @DayOfWeek = (DATEPART(weekday,@Date) + 7 -
                  DATEPART(weekday,'20140406')) % 7; -- 1 to 5 = Weekday
```

And now you should be able to continue writing it as a function rather than a stored procedure.

---

> If it's safe to do this I'd certainly prefer to so I don't need to change any calling code.

Which you *would* have to do if you did change your function into a stored procedure. There's no syntax where you can look at the call and ever be in doubt of whether a stored procedure or a function is being invoked - they always use different syntaxes. A procedure is executed by being the first piece of text in a batch or by being preceded by the `EXEC` keyword and no parentheses.

A function, on the other hand, always has to have parentheses applied when calling it, and must appear as an expression within a larger statement (such as `SELECT`). You cannot `EXEC` a function, nor call one by it being the first piece of text in a batch.

Comment: nice one!  I think this is actually the option I'm going to go for.  It took me a few examples with pen and paper to follow what's actually going on there.  Its a bit like a decoder ring!

Answer (score 1):

An out param could be of (almost) any valid datatype, RETURN is always an int, not necessarily 0 or 1.

Because you can't use a procedure as a query source (it's not a table), to consume a return value from a procedure, declare a variable and exec the procedure like this:

```
create procedure p as
-- some code
return 13
go

declare @r int
exec @r = p
select @r
```

I wouldn't call it piggybacking, it's a regular way to return a success/error code for example. But how you interprete the return value is entirely up to calling code.

Functions, otoh, can be used as a query source, if table-valued, or as a scalar value in select list or where clause etc. But you can't modify data inside functions, and there are other restrictions with them (as you've learned already). Furthermore, functions can have nasty impact on performance (except the inline table-valued functions, they're pretty much safe to use).

Comment: thanks for the answer!  I think this probably answers the questions at the bottom more than the other but I've awarded it to the other guy because that's more useful to me.  It's good to know there's nothing wierd going on with the return values

Comment: I've not had that dilemma before - normally end up answering my own questions, they're usually something obscure in either c# or wpf!