# Insert Into with Random Generated Chars

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using this statement to put entries from one table into another. I need for the randomly generated part to be unique for each record pulled to table A, but as it is now its the same for all of them.

How do I fix this query so that the @CharacterData variable to be unique for each record pulled into tableA?

UPDATE: Moved the random generated stuff into a stored procedure dbo.RandChars

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RandChars]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (@Length int)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
declare @BinaryData varbinary(max)
, @CharacterData varchar(max)
set @BinaryData=crypt_gen_random(@Length) 
set @CharacterData=cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@BinaryData"))', 'varchar(max)')
PRINT @CharacterData
END
```

How do I utilize this stored procedure to get that unique random string into each row's token record?

```
Insert INTO TableA
(TableA.firstname,
TableA.token,
TableA.email,
TableA.emailstatus, 
TableA.language, 
TableA.remindersent, 
TableA.attribute_1,
TableA.attribute_2)


SELECT TableB.[Franchise Location], 
[**random string for token**],
TableB.[Franchise Email],
'OK', 
'en',  
'N', 
TableB.[Order Number], 
TableB.[Invoice Date]
FROM TableB
WHERE TableB.[Order Date] >= dateadd(DAY, -1, Convert(date, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: It looks like your issue is that binarydata is called once. binarydata is used to create CharacterData so it will use the same random characters every time

Comment: Why not put the random generator in a function, so when you call the select it should pull each time.

Comment: I like the function idea. If i do create a function, and the tables are in separate db's which db do i create it in?

Comment: It shouldnt matter actually. How are you doing this across databases. If your query can pull from 2 databases then you should be able to put your function in either.

Comment: OK that makes sense. My issue now is it seems I can't use crypt_gen_random in a function. Keeps spitting out "Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'Crypt_Gen_Random' within a function."

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389503/invalid-use-side-effecting-operator-insert-within-a-function

Comment: Not very pretty but try moving it into its own sproc... you can still use it.

Comment: That's fine by me, but afaik you can't use a stored procedure in a select statement. How do I utilize this to get the data into my table?

Comment: good point.... thats a very interesting problem you have :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87918/discussion-between-nicholas-j-dininno-and-logixologist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select a value from a column in a nested select:

```
--> set up test data...
create table tableB ( id int )
create table tableA ( id int, rnd varchar(max ) )
go
insert tableB( id ) values( 1 ) ,( 2 ), ( 3 ) --> etc
go

--> do the work...
insert tableA( id, rnd )
select 
    sub.id,
    cast( '' as xml ).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column( "rx" ) )', 'varchar(max)' )
from
    (
    select
        id,
        crypt_gen_random( 4 ) rx
        from 
        tableB
    ) as sub

go

--> inspect the results...
select * from tableA
go

--> cleanup...
drop table tableA
drop table tableB
```

...and skip using a procedure altogether.

**Edit:**

So, using your example, the syntax would be more like:

```
insert TableA
(
    firstname,
    token,
    email,
    emailstatus, 
    [language], 
    remindersent, 
    attribute_1,
    attribute_2
)
select 
    location, 
    cast( '' as xml ).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column( "token" ) )', 'varchar(max)' ),
    email,
    emailstatus,
    [language],
    remindersent,
    attribute_1,
    attribute_2
from 
    (
        select 
            TableB.[FranchiseLocation] location,
            crypt_gen_random(30) as token, 
            TableB.[Franchise Email] email, 
            'OK' emailstatus,
            'en' [language], 
            'N' remindersent, 
            TableB.[Order Number] attribute_1, 
            TableB.[Invoice Date] attribute_2 
        from 
            TableB
        where 
            TableB.[Order Date] >= dateadd(DAY, -1, Convert(date, GETDATE()))
    ) as x
```

I don't have those tables - so this is a try-it-before-you-buy-it attempt :-)

Comment: ok so the query becomes: SELECT TableB.[Franchise Location], 
(SELECT cast( '' as xml ).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column( "rx" ) )', 'varchar(max)' ) from (select crypt_gen_random(30) rx)) as sub, ,
TableB.[Franchise Email],
'OK', 
'en',  
'N', 
TableB.[Order Number], 
TableB.[Invoice Date]
FROM TableB
WHERE TableB.[Order Date] >= dateadd(DAY, -1, Convert(date, GETDATE()))  but I get Incorrect syntax near ')' for the part before 'as sub'

Comment: This wants to work, but I get "String or binary data would be truncated"

Comment: I think I got it. I had to change 'varchar(max)' to 'varchar(30)' to match.

Comment: How wide is the token column?  That random 30 turns into 31 or 32 characters (Base64 binary appends one or two "=" characters - which you may not want)

Comment: btw, I followed your approach of using the `crypt_gen_random(30)`, but there may be better solution if you have a key column in your data source: use `hashbytes( 'sha1', convert( varbinary(4),[some-int-key-column] ) )`.  This function computes a 20-byte hash on the value you pass in and is _so unique_ that a lot of systems rely on it for a content fingerprint.  Here, I'm assuming an int key column and converting it to varbinary - hashbytes requires varbinary or character data.  You could get away with a smaller token column this way, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88038/discussion-between-nicholas-j-dininno-and-clay).

Comment: The actual token column in the destination table is nvarchar 35, and there is a tid column of identity int and it's the pk of that table.