# "select into" in select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I need this query inside a select statement in another query, i have tried to put it inside a function and call it from the select, but i get errors maybe because non-scalar statements are not allowed in a function. How can i proceed?

```
SELECT Tip.NombreTipoMov 
                    INTO #tabla_temp
                    FROM ut_sgt_Movimientos_t Reg
                    INNER JOIN  ut_sgt_TiposMovimientos_m Tip
                                ON Reg.id_TipoMov = Tip.id_TipoMov
                    WHERE Reg.id_Registro = @IdRegistro

                    DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100)

                    UPDATE #tabla_temp
                    SET @data = @data + ' ' + NombreTipoMov

                    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@data))

                    DROP TABLE #tabla_temp
```

This is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uf_sgt_ObtieneTiposMovimientosXRegistroVehiculo
(
    @IdRegistro  INTEGER
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Retorno VARCHAR(100)
```

`SET @Retorno =  (   SELECT Tip.NombreTipoMov 
                    INTO #tabla_temp
                    FROM ut_sgt_Movimientos_t Reg
                    INNER JOIN  ut_sgt_TiposMovimientos_m Tip
                                ON Reg.id_TipoMov = Tip.id_TipoMov
                    WHERE Reg.id_Registro = @IdRegistro

                    DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100)

                    UPDATE #tabla_temp
                    SET @data = @data + ' ' + NombreTipoMov 

                    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@data))

                    DROP TABLE #tabla_temp
                )

RETURN @Retorno END GO`

This is the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
>
> Illegal UPDATE statement within a scalar SQL function.
>
> Illegal SELECT statement within a scalar SQL function.
>
> Illegal DROP TABLE statement within a scalar SQL function.
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Could you provide the error message you receive?

Comment: edited with the error message

Comment: @HermanZun perhaps initialize your new data variable, set data = ''

Comment: replace brackets with double/single quotes. i.e. `SET @Retorno = "..."`

Comment: Your function make no sense. You never initialize `@data` ,When we set a value to a variable we use select ie. "SELECT `@Retorno` = ". Please clarify your purpose for the function. And lot of other problem I see .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have temp tables in a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844854/is-it-possible-to-have-temp-tables-in-a-function)